# Open Source, Multiple JVM Monitor web application options?

Tags: jvm, performance

I'm looking for an open source web application to monitor several JVM's over several servers. I've done some searching and found multiple options that are failing each in their own way.

I need it to:
1. Be a web application
2. Monitor several JVM's across multiple servers
3. Specifically monitor Heap/Perm Gen memory space
4. Be able to set off an email alert based on thresholds for both of these.

I found another question posted 2 years ago that is still updated, though it specifically calls out Tomcat, and doesn't allow for JVM's alone:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242958/best-tools-to-monitor-tomcat

Looking into JavaMelody and a few others, from what I gather, they're not able to monitor multiple JVM's across multiple servers.

EDIT: Actually looking into this more and talking to associates more knowledgeable than I, most of the JVM's are instances of Tomcat, but we also use a few Jetty servers that also need to be covered.

Further research looks like a solution around OpenNMS (http://www.opennms.org/) might be a bit of overkill, but in the end would hit all the requirements, anyone think otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaMelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki) is able to do all these, except email alerts based on thresholds.

It can be used to monitor a single webapp, but you can also start a centralized collect server to monitor several webapps in multiple servers, separately or aggregated. See the centralized collect server in [Advanced user guide](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest another approach I've used and it seemed beneficial. I used nagios + pnp4nagios and created a custom script that connects to the virtual machines and uses JMX to obtain relevant stuff. I've also written a custom web app that does the same without the nagios part.